# BLE Response time increases gradually

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using BLE communication to connect with sensor.
On continues commands the response time keeps increasing by few milliseconds every time and finally gets disconnected due to timeout.

Platform - Xamarin Forms.
OS -  Android
Plugin -  Plugin.BLE

I tried autoconnect to true and false.

Comment: What happens if you connect from an app such as nRF Connect fro Android and not send any commands? Is the connection maintained or does the disconnection eventually happen anyway?

Comment: So in nRF or in our app, if we do no send commands continuously then there is no delay or disconnection.

Comment: Can you send the commands from the nRF app? i.e. write the same string from the nRF app to the same characteristic that your app is writing to. You can then inspect in detail what is happening using nRF app's debug screen.